# Can "non" be used as a separate word?

Tags: negation, hyphens, prefixes

I used non trivial and a grammar correction website shows it is wrong and should be either `non-trivial` or `nontrivial`.

> 1. x appears in a non trivial number of pages

Or

> 2. x appears in a non-trivial number of pages

Or

> 3. x appears in a nontrivial number of pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct spelling is either non-trivial or nontrivial. (British writers tend to prefer the hyphenated form)

"Non" is not used as an independent word, it may be a prefix or it can be written hyphenated.  An independent word "non" is used in some Latin phrases eg *non compos mentis* (meaning "not of sound mind").  This is discussed in the wiktionary [usage notes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/non-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your grammar checker.  "Non-" is a prefix, not a separate word.  It can either be fully attached to the word it modifies, or attached with a hyphen.

"Not" can often be used as a separate word instead of "non-".

The following example #4 is technically acceptable, but is not as natural as any of examples 2, 3, and 5.  Examples 2 and 3 are more natural than example #5:

> 4. x appears in a not trivial number of pages
> 5. The number of pages that x appears in is not trivial.

Comment: X appears on pages, not in pages.